# Segmentation fault when trying to store a pointer to another pointer variable

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I started programming with C a while ago and tried to create a Lexical Analyzer (which I already did in Java) for practice. As an excercise I created a Linked List for the Tokens. Everything except removing elements works fine.

token.h

```
#ifndef TOKEN_H
#define TOKEN_H

typedef struct TOKEN_STRUCT {

   enum TokenType {

      ...

   } type;

   char* contents;

   struct TOKEN_STRUCT* next;

   size_t start_position, end_position;

} Token;

...

Token* init_token(enum TokenType type, char* contents, size_t start_position, size_t end_position);

Token* remove_token_last(Token* head);

...

#endif
```

token.c

```
#include "token.h"

...
Token* init_token(enum TokenType type, char* contents, size_t start_position, size_t end_position)
{
   Token* token = (Token*) malloc(sizeof(struct TOKEN_STRUCT));
   if(token == NULL) {
      printf("Couldn't allocate memory for the token.\n");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }

   token->type = type;
   token->contents = contents;
   token->start_position = start_position;
   token->end_position = end_position;
   return token;
}

// This is the function which throws the Segmentation fault
Token* remove_token_last(Token* head)
{
   Token* current = head;
   while(current->next != NULL)
      current = current->next;
   Token* return_token = current->next;
   printf("remove: %u, %s\n", return_token->type, return_token->contents); <- And this line creates the Segmentation fault.
   current->next = NULL;
   return return_token;
}
```

Now to my question: Why does it throw the error, can't I define another pointer variable (Token* current = ...;) which stores the next Token* (current->next) for later usage?

Also I'm new to C-Programming and would appreicate some answers which will help me out of this situation. Even if there is something I could do better, please correct me!

Edit: 
I feel a little stupid, but I'll let the question remain. Maybe ("hopefully") there are people who have looked just as carelessly as me. :D The Problem was, that "current->next" can't be anything else than NULL, because when quitting the while-loop the "current->next" will be NULL due to the condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`return_token` is null when you try to print its fields.

```
// This is the function which throws the Segmentation fault
Token* remove_token_last(Token* head)
{
   Token* current = head;
   while(current->next != NULL) // looping while current->next != NULL
      current = current->next;
   Token* return_token = current->next; // now its NULL so return_token is NULL too
   // therefore in the printf you referencing to a NULL pointer fields which
   // cause segmentation error
   printf("remove: %u, %s\n", return_token->type, return_token->contents); <- And this line creates the Segmentation fault.
   current->next = NULL;
   return return_token;
}
```

Comment: Okay.. Now I'm feeling kinda dumb.. Thank you for your quick response! Next time I need to look closer. Thanks!

Comment: Do not feel dumb, it is easy to make mistakes with pointers and stuff. Glad if it helped.